# Schedule with delete query in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, scheduled-tasks, spring-transactions

Recently, I'm implementing schedule which is running every 30 seconds.
This schedule fetch oldest record from H2 database and if this one is older than 120 days from now, delete from database.
but, when I use delete jpa transaction, it doesn't work.

Someone else have similar problem, I follow this answer, but this solution isn't solve my problem.
[Spring4 @Scheduled @Transaction throws no transaction is in progress at flush for mutliple dataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248846/spring4-scheduled-transaction-throws-no-transaction-is-in-progress-at-flush-fo)

Here is my Schedule source code and configuration.

DBCofig.java

```
package movingjin.tradingbot.config;
...
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = {"movingjin.tradingbot"})
public class DBConfig{
    final String name = "batch";

    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("movingjin.tradingbot");
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("default");
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return tm;
    }
}
```

JobScheduler.java

```
package movingjin.tradingbot.batch.tickerHistory;

...
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JobScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobConfiguration jobConfiguration;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 10000, fixedDelay = 30000)
    public void runJob() {

        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);

        try {

            jobLauncher.run(jobConfiguration.job(), jobParameters);

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException | org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException e) {

            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

JobConfiguration.java

```
package movingjin.tradingbot.batch.tickerHistory;

...
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String instanceId;

    @Autowired
    private TickerJpaInterface tickerRepository;

    @Bean
    public Job job(){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .on("FAILED")
                .end()
                .from(step1())
                .on("*")
                .to(step2())
                .on("FAILED")
                .end()
                .from(step2())
                .on("*")
                .to(step3())
                .on("*") 
                .end()
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {

                    log.info("======= Start ticker history batch =======");
                    for(Coin.Token token: Coin.Token.values()) {

                        List<Ticker> tickers = tickerRepository.findByCoinNameAndTimeStampBefore(token.name(), LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(120));
                        for(Ticker ticker: tickers)
                        {
                            log.info(ticker.getTimeStamp().toString() + "fetch and deleting: " + ticker.getIdx());
                            tickerRepository.deleteByIdx(ticker.getIdx());
                        }
                    }

                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    log.info("testbug2");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step3(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    log.info("testbug3");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

}
```

It is JPA repository.

```
package movingjin.tradingbot.batch.tickerHistory.repository;

import movingjin.tradingbot.batch.tickerHistory.domain.Ticker;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;


public interface TickerJpaInterface extends JpaRepository<Ticker, Long>, TickerInterface {
    @Override
    List<Ticker> findByCoinNameAndTimeStampBefore(String userName, LocalDateTime days);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    //@Transactional(transactionManager = "jpaTransactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.NEVER, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    //@Transactional(transactionManager = "jpaTransactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    //@Modifying
    //@Query("delete from TICKER_HISTORY t where t.idx = ?1")
    void deleteByIdx(Long idx);

}
```

So, any idea to solve this problem??

Comment: Try injecting the repository into your tasklet, rather than referencing the outer scope.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you solve it ?